# NamedJdbcTemplate update issue

Tags: java, database, oracle, spring-jdbc

there is a issue that when use namedJdbcTemplate to insert a data to Oracle, a issue occurred and the exception is

```
"ORA-01722: invalid number
; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-01722: invalid number"
```

my code is:

```
parameters.put("cancelMessage", message);
parameters.put("cancelStatus", cancelStatus);
parameters.put("requestSOAP", requestSOAP);
parameters.put("cancelTimes", Integer.valueOf(cancelTimes));
String newSql = "insert into XXSTT_AUTO_CANCEL_REQ_STATUS (AUTO_CANCEL_STATUS_ID, REQUEST_ID, CANCEL_STATUS, CANCEL_TIMES, CANCEL_MESSAGE,\n" +
                "                                          LATEST_FLAG, CREATE_DATE, LAST_MODIFIED_DATE, CANCEL_REQUEST_SOAP)\n" +
                "values (XXSTT_AUTO_CANCEL_REQ_STATUS_S.nextval, :requestId, :cancelStatus, :cancelTimes, :cancelMessage, 'Y', sysdate,\n" +
                "        sysdate, :requestSOAP)";
namedJdbcTemplate.update(newSql, parameters);
```

cancelTimes is a int number, in Oracle, the data type is Number, so what issue here.
Pls help me, thanks

Comment: in the parameters you don't define `:requestId`, beside remove the `\n` ?!

Comment: @YCF_L sorry for this mistake, I forgot to tie this parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please remove `\n` from code where you have added in code.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but i don't know why remove \n here.Is there any reason to remove \n?

Comment: An ORA-01722 error occurs when an attempt is made to convert a character string into a number, and the string cannot be converted into a number.

Without seeing your table definition, it looks like you're trying to convert the numeric sequence at the end of your values list to a number, and the spaces that delimit it are throwing this error. But based on the information you've given us, it could be happening on any field (other than the first one).

Comment: here is my table define
`create table XXSTT_AUTO_CANCEL_REQ_STATUS
(
  AUTO_CANCEL_STATUS_ID NUMBER not null
    primary key,
  REQUEST_ID            NUMBER,
  CANCEL_STATUS         NUMBER,
  CANCEL_TIMES          NUMBER,
  CANCEL_MESSAGE        VARCHAR2(256),
  LATEST_FLAG           VARCHAR2(8),
  CREATE_DATE           DATE,
  LAST_MODIFIED_DATE    DATE,
  CANCEL_REQUEST_SOAP   VARCHAR2(1024)
)`
you are right, i make a mistake here when create table

Answer (score 1):

```
Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<>();
parameters.put("requestId", requestId);
```

i have define this parameter and I think it cause by 'Cancel_times', is right?